# how to restore database in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I am using sqlyog in office. But at my home I have mysql gui. now how can I backup a database from sqlyog and restore it mysql gui? any idea please

Comment: by `mysql gui`, you mean mysql workbench?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why over complicate things?

Create backup

`mysqldump -u <user> -p<password> <database> > backup.sql`

Restore

`mysql -u <user> -p<password> <database> < backup.sql`