# How to restore a duplicate database with MySQL Administrator?

Tags: mysql, mysql-backup, mysqladmin, mysqladministrator

I just started working with a client that has MySQL 5.5 and MySQL Administrator v1.2.17 over Windows 2012 Server. My task is to duplicate a live database into the same server - essentially copy dblive into dbtest.

I used the app to create a backup .sql file, without a drop table. I'd like to use the restore mechanism in this app, purely out of convenience and to be able to document a simple process for the client. But every resource I find is vague on detail, assuming that the restore will replace the original. So I'm hoping to get a concrete solution here.

The restore asks for Target Schema, whether Original or Another. This is the only option, it doesn't say "database name". (I'll accept a "duh, that's what you want".) The tip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/165675/190955) suggests this should be simple and quick, but the follow-up comment says this app can't handle "big" databases. The .sql file for this is 250MB, I'm not sure if that qualifies as big.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15050223/190955) tip suggests using the mysql command-line, but there's no confirmation that it works for restoring to a different database name. Most other solutions I've found rely on complex queries, notes like "don't do that", twiddling with configs, etc. I'm hoping someone can propose a simple solution, even if not using this one utility. I'm not a MySQL stud, more of a developer, so please be don't beat me up. Thanks.

Comment: Just edit the database name in the SQL before you load it.

Comment: Still need to check on this. If the solution is as easy as that then I'll ask you to re-post as an Answer so that I can give you proper credit. That said, the original points of the inquiry haven't really been answered. Thanks.